# Chai: Assert a variable does not exist

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

How do I use Chai to verify that some variable does not exist?

That is to say, my js doesn't have a statement `var never_declared`, and I want to verify that there isn't any such variable.

I have tried all of following, but Karma keeps complaining "Can't find variable: never_declared".  Which is exactly what I'm trying to test.

```
should.not.exist(never_declared);
expect(never_declared).to.not.exist;
expect(never_declared).to.not.exist;
expect(never_declared).to.be.undefined;
expect(never_declared).to.be.an('undefined');
assert.isNotObject(never_declared);
assert.isUndefined(never_declared);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Karma has a problem with it you can use another valid Chai form like:

```
expect(typeof never_declared).to.eq('undefined');
```

or

```
expect(typeof never_declared === "undefined").to.be.true;
```